# Calcular a quantidade de números pares em uma tupla de forma recursiva

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso de ajuda para criar uma função recursiva que encontre e some os elementos pares de uma tupla, agradeceria imensamente a ajuda.

```
def conta_pares(t):
   '''conta_pares : tuplo -> inteiro
   recebe tuplo de inteiros e devolve o numero de elementos pares no tuplo'''
   if t == ():
      return 0
   else:
      #t = (t[1:])
      #if a % 2 == 0:
      return t[0] + conta_pares(t[1:])
```

Comment: Desculpe amigo, realmente é apenas para contar os elementos pares do tuplo de forma recursiva.

Comment: E por que o seu `if` está comentado?

Comment: Pq nao sei como usar neste caso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta verificar se o valor é par verificando o resto de divisão por 2. Se for zero é par; se for 1 é ímpar. Quando for par, você deve somar 1 mais a quantidade de números pares no restante da tupla; se for ímpar, deve retornar apenas a quantidade de número pares no restante da tupla.

```
def pares(t):
    if not t:
        return 0

    par = (t[0] % 2 == 0)

    if par:
        return 1 + pares(t[1:])
    else:
        return pares(t[1:])
```

Ou, em uma forma simplificada:

```
return (1 if par else 0) + pares(t[1:])
```

Se você considerar que o tipo booleano, no Python, é uma especialização do tipo inteiro, sendo `False` igual a zero e `True` igual a 1, poderia fazer apenas:

```
def pares(t):
    if not t:
        return 0            
    return (t[0] % 2 == 0) + pares(t[1:]
```

Comment: Muuuuito obrigado amigo.